# Graph service issue?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have not been able to create any subscriptions via graph API for several days. We tested with Graph Explorer with the same result.

To test, go to graph explorer, sign in, select post, uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions , leave the post body empty (it didn't matter anyway), you would receive this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
---Response Body---
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "InvalidRequest",
            "message": "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.",
            "innerError": {
                "date": "2020-08-26T19:15:31",
                "request-id": "b3c6ef07-6007-46e6-9ecb-6a8ce5a07d88"
            }
        }
```

Since there is proper JSON response body, the client itself should have reached the graph server properly. It seems the graph service itself was not able to reach some downstream service?

Any ideas?

Here's [screenshot](https://nexiwave.com/images/Selection_188.png).

Comment: can please try the post, request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions with the JSON body in the request and let us know If you are facing any issue. Please provide us the request body in the question.

Comment: @Sruthi J- MSFT Identity : graph explorer still receive the same error: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." in the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually realized the "SSL/TLS" could mean graph wasn't able to open TLS channel to the callback url. Updated openssl/apache of the callback server fixed the issue. Several new ciphers were added in the latest openssl, so the issue was very likely because graph now requires one of those new ciphers. A better message in the graph response JSON (indicating the SSL/TLS to the callback server) would have helped a lot;).